# How do I find the web root in civicrm.settings.php?

Tags: configuration

I'd like to set

```
$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir'] =
```

to a files directory relative to the web root. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you need to do this via the settings file? This is easy to do via the UI as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to set those is using Civi::settings()->set('......').

In the UI it is Administer/System Settings/Directories.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Via the UI you can use the [cms.root] token click on the "Blue Question Mark" in the help text at the top of Adminsister/System Settings/Directories to display a notice which lists the available variables and what they will be expanded as.